# Imagview inside cardview not working rounded corner in emulator but works in xml preview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-cardview, rounded-corners

How can I fix this? Imageview rounded corner perfectly works in preview but in emulator and physical device there is no rounded corner effect.

Preview window XML

[image]

Emulator

[image]

That is my code.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/materialCardView2"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/test_iv"
        android:src="@drawable/rider"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: it work perfectly fine in my physical device please clean and rebuilt your app and run again

Comment: I tried it but still not working 

Comment: try invalidate chche and restart

Comment: Still not working bro but it works 2 days ago and now still not working. Do i need to change some gradle and dependencies

Comment: try to upgrade gradle file

Comment: share your gradle_wrapper.property and project level build.gradle

Comment: gradle_wrapper.property [link](https://i.ibb.co/8BCxwbQ/Screenshot-2023-01-13-17-31-20.png)         project level gradle [link](https://i.ibb.co/dL03TyC/Screenshot-2023-01-13-17-32-48.png)

Comment: the last option is clear cheche and storage of your app from application manager and run it again

Comment: Still not working bro. Btw thanks for your help